# Cannot run java.class file in tomcat7's webapp from cron

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7, classpath

I have a webapp running in a tomcat7 using struts and hibernate framework. I have inside this app a class with a main method that I would like to call out of the app (from crontab in a linux environment). In my local machine, for run it, I only have to right-click over the file and click on 'Run File' Netbeans' option.
But in production's server, I don't know how to run this file from cron, because if I do $java path-to-the-file.class I am facing an error (class not found). I think that it is a problem from classpath but I could't find a solution for my problem. Could anyone help me?

Comment: grmbl ... how can people write/deploy entire web applications and not know how to start a Java class from the command line? Isn't that covered in every single Java tutorial? ... sorry.

Comment: You need to specify all the required folders with class fiels and all required libraries on the commandline like so: java -cp "/path/to/webapp/classes;/path/to/webapp/lib/bla.jar;[..]" when using java6+ you may be able to use Wildcards. You might need to figure out if you need to initialize Hibernate differently when running standalone (you probably should have to!)

Comment: Have you considered using a Java-based scheduler such as [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to run the timed background job directly inside your webapp rather than running it externally?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the classpath to the java command line.  The classpath is the path where Java will search for .class files. For example if your .class file had no package declaration and was in the tomcat folder
/servers/tomcat7/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/mymain.class you would use the command line

```
java -cp /servers/tomcat7/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes mymain
```

I suggest you read up on the Java classpath

Comment: This would be a good read for you http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I tried like you have said before asking here. Nevertheless I will read the article you have suggested me. Thanks.

Comment: You will also need to add all the jars that your class depends on.. If you are using > java 1.5 use the command
    java -cp /servers/tomcat7/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes:/servers/tomcat7/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/* mymain